# How to assign an order to field in a many to many field

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, many-to-one

This is my first django project so I'm still learning. I Django project of Formula One Races and Racers. The Race model looks like this,

```
class Race(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date = models.DateField()
    track = models.URLField()
    comments = models.TextField()

    @property
    def has_passed(self):
        return self.date < date.today()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["date"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and the racers look like this,

```
class Players(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    team = models.ForeignKey(
        Teams,
        related_name = "players_team",
        on_delete = models.CASCADE
    )
    races = models.ManyToManyField(
        Race,
        related_name= "results",
        )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to be able to assign a different order to the racer for each race to show the race results. How would I be able to assign this order? Thank you

I tried to manually assign ordering on by creating a result model, I feel like that is clunky.

Comment: Do you want to save the order in your model or do you just want to show the sorted results of the race?

Comment: I want to show the sorted results for each race. I was assuming the best way to do this was to save the order in the model, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Imo the best way would be to create a result model for each player-race like this:

```
class Result(models.Model):
    race = models.OneToOneField(Race,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    player = models.OneToOneField(Players,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField()


    class Meta:
        ordering = ["order"]
```

This way you can easily query the results for each race and I would suggest you to change class name from Players to Player and you can add a clean method to not allow one order more than once per race. Having an extra model for the relationship will make it more robust and easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I believe an adequate solution would be to store the results inside the `many-to-many` relationship table using [extra fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships):

models.py

```py
class Track(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    url = models.URLField()


class Driver(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team, related_name="players_team", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    races = models.ManyToManyField(Track, through="Race")


class Race(models.Model):
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    grid = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(Comment, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.driver.name} grid {self.grid}"
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["grid"]
```

Note that `comments` is now a `ManyToManyField`, since the field name was in plural in your `Model` I assume that you want a race to have many `Comments` (made by different users).

Here is a simple [`testing`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/overview/#module-django.test) example:

tests.py

```py
class RaceTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        """
        Setup teams, drivers and one track
        """
        team_rbr = Team.objects.create(name="Oracle Red Bull Racing")
        self.rbr_driver1 = Driver.objects.create(
            name="Max Verstappen", country="Netherlands", team=team_rbr
        )
        self.rbr_driver2 = Driver.objects.create(
            name="Sergio Perez", country="Mexico", team=team_rbr
        )

        team_am = Team.objects.create(name="Aston Martin")
        self.am_driver1 = Driver.objects.create(
            name="Fernando Alonso", country="Spain", team=team_am
        )
        self.am_driver2 = Driver.objects.create(
            name="Lance Stroll", country="Canada", team=team_am
        )

        # Setup track
        self.monza_track = Track.objects.create(
            name="Autodromo Nazionale di Monza",
            location="Italy",
            url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monza_Circuit",
        )

    def test_race_grid(self):
        """
        Create a 'Race' and check the grid position
        """
        race_date = date(2022, 9, 11)
        Race.objects.create(
            driver=self.rbr_driver1, 
            track=self.monza_track, 
            grid=1, 
            date=race_date
        )
        Race.objects.create(
            driver=self.rbr_driver2, 
            track=self.monza_track, 
            grid=6, 
            date=race_date
        )
        Race.objects.create(
            driver=self.am_driver1, 
            track=self.monza_track, 
            grid=18, 
            date=race_date
        )
        Race.objects.create(
            driver=self.am_driver2, 
            track=self.monza_track, 
            grid=19, 
            date=race_date
        )

        monza_race = Race.objects.filter(track=self.monza_track, date=race_date)

        # 1st place was super max (the first element of the queryset)
        self.assertEqual(monza_race.first().driver.name, "Max Verstappen")
        # "Last" place was stroll (the last element of the queryset)
        self.assertEqual(monza_race.last().driver.name, "Lance Stroll")

        print(monza_race)
        # Output sample:
        # <QuerySet [
        #     <Race: Max Verstappen grid 1>, 
        #     <Race: Sergio Perez grid 6>, 
        #     <Race: Fernando Alonso grid 18>, 
        #     <Race: Lance Stroll grid 19>
        # ]>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I'm alittle confused as to this is allow me to assign a position or result to each driver for each race? Is it through the driver foreign key you have in the race model?

Comment: No, the `grid` field is the one that holds the driver position within a particular `Race`. I will try to improve my answer to clarify this, as soon as I can!

Comment: So, I have added a test file to show you how the relation would work. Also, I have altered the `__str__` magic method of  the `Race` model so you can better see the `QuerySet` ordering. Hopefully this will help to elucidate this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Django implements a `ManyToManyField` by making a (hidden) table with two `ForeignKey`s to the two models between which you span the relation.

The good news is, you can specify a model yourself that acts as model in between, and thus add extra fields to that relation, like:

```
class Race(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    # …


class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    # …
    races = models.ManyToManyField(
        Race,
        through='Result'
        related_name='results',
    )


class Result(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    race = models.ForeignKey(Race, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordering = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('ordering',)
```

For a `Race` object we can then get the result by ordering these through the `ordering` field:

```
my_race = Race.objects.get(pk=1)  # get a Race object
players = my_race.results.order_by('result_set__ordering')
```

You can for example add `Result` to the `ModelAdmin` and there change the `ordering` of any combination of the `Race` and `Player`.